# Holding either &str or String in a variable

Tags: rust

Suppose I define a struct with a string field. The field should:

1. Be able to hold the string ownership (e.g., when I want to populate it with a value generated `format`),
2. Also be able to hold an immutable reference as well (in cases when the string is already owned elsewhere and I don't want to wastefully clone it).

How would I express this ("either `&str` or `String`") in Rust?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a builtin type for that, [`std::borrow::Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) (short for **C**lone **O**n **W**rite). By specifying `Cow<'a, str>`, you can store `&'a str` as well as `String`. `Cow` derefs to `str` so you can call `str` methods, and provides the [`to_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html#method.to_mut) and [`into_owned()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html#method.into_owned) methods for when you need to call `String` methods.

Comment: This is not a builtin type: it is defined in the standard library. You could easily write your own Cow with the same performance characteristics; there is no "compiler magic" here.

Comment: @MarkSaving In some sense it is built in: the standard library comes with the language. Builtin doesn't necessarily means compiler magic. But I don't think there is a reason to argue about terminology.

Answer (score 1):

The std::borrow::Cow type is sufficient for your usecase as suggested in another answer. In case you want some custom type with additional constraints, you can try defining your own enum as below.

In Rust, you can use an enum to represent the field that can hold either a String or an &str. Enums allow you to define a type that can have multiple variants, each with its own data.

```
enum MyString {
  Owned(String),
  Borrowed(&'static str),
}

struct MyStruct {
  field: MyString,
}
```

In above example, the MyString enum has two variants: Owned, which holds a String and represents the owned string ownership, and Borrowed, which holds an &str and represents an immutable reference to a string.

You can then use the MyStruct struct and populate the field with either a String or an &str, depending on your needs.

Comment: This is true in the general case, but defining an enum in this case is bad because the standard library already provides one.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman totally agree with you. The approach of creating your own only justifies when you want something custom.

Comment: `&'static str` can't hold on to a reference to a "String owned elsewhere".